# How update lock works in database.

Tags: sql-server, transactions, locking

When I read the documentation about sql server database 2008 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx, I know there are three types of lock mode:

- Exclusive(X)
- Shared(S)
- Update(U)

I understand how exclusive lock and shared lock works. The only problem is how would the Update（U） lock work under the following scenario:

- Transaction **T1** begin and get **shared lock** on **rowA**
- Transaction **T2** begin and get **update lock** on **rowA**
- Transaction **T2** is going to update **rowA**, therefore, request to upgrade lock from update mode to exclusive mode. Currently, **T1** has not release the shared lock on **row A**
- ？？？

The problem is how would the database behave in this case? Since we know the exclusive lock can not be acquired while another transaction hold the shared lock on the resource.

Will the database terminate **T1** and upgrade lock of **T2** ?
Or will it wait until the **T1** release the shared lock ?

Comment: If there is a deadlock victim in sql server, it is always going to be the process with the least amount of locks/resources allocated. If a SELECT and an UPDATE statement conflict, almost always the SELECT will be the victim as less locks have been allocated for the operation.

Comment: Thanks! So you mean the shared lock held by T1 will be forced to release when there is a request from T2 for upgrading "update lock" to “exclusive lock” ? T1 will be terminated or suspended until it can acquire shared lock back ?

Comment: I would be speculating so I can not answer. I once inherited a heavily trafficked database and had to throw NOLOCKS on all non-important reads. I was getting many deadlock graphs emailed to me a day. The victim was never a reader and the deadlocks always occurred between a reader and a writer, very similar to the situation you described above. The lock comment I stated was based on my research on that issue.